# Microsoft Bot Framework without azure subscription process for production launch

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have created the Bot using Microsoft Bot framework in C# and I have hosted the Bot in the cloud environment (Pivotal cloud Foundry) not in Azure. I have registered the bot in [the link](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new) to enable webchat using direct line and I have received the appid and app password for that. I Understand that registration is free without azure subscription to enable the webchat. I have red the [forum link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/register-bot-without-azure-process/m-p/1490808) which clearly tells that subscription is not required for bot registration if the bot is hosted in the non-azure environment. Now my Bot is working without any issues.

But my question is shall i proceed with same process for production environment. is there any limitation on this?

Comment: you're free to run wherever you want. However, you'll be responsible for the scaling part

Comment: What you mean by scaling part here? My Bot is perfectly working without any issues. So shall i proceed the bot registration  for Production environment

Comment: when you expose to public, if it gets too many requests, you will need to scale (add a copy of it in a separate server and configure a load balancer to route the requests). This is all done by Azure easily...

Comment: Thanks for your response.My problem is I don't have azure subscription ,I want to go with free bot registration()  for the production environment. I am trying to understand whether the application in prod environment will be stable or not ,since we couldn't face any issues in the development environment. Kindly advise on this.

Comment: @Naveen: You might face intermittent issues with the bot functionality. It's recommended to register Azure bot in azure subscription. Don't see alternatives.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again. whether is it not possible without azure subscription? As we are   planning to remove the azure subscription and host it in GCP environment .Currently my application running on Azure. Kindly suggest.